# Why do we use <div>#root instead of <body>?

Tags: reactjs

So, as I understand a React app can be rendered inside pretty much any HTML element  we point to by a selector. Why is the convention to use additional `<div>` with id of `root`, instead of just `<body>`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the creator of Redux (Dan Abramov), this is what he has to say about rendering to the body.

> If you render directly into document.body, you risk collisions with
>   scripts that do something with it (e.g. Google Font Loader or third
>   party browser extensions) which produce very weird and hard to debug
>   errors in production. React warns you if you attempt to do this.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1568

Comment: This doesn't explain much though. A list of actual common problems would be nice to have (placed here or linked). And scripts can mess with any element, so it's just that with body it tends to happen more often, right? And isn't it a flaw of those scripts which should be reported to their authors and fixed, possibly with a universal solution or at least guidance from the React team?

Comment: It's usually not a flaw that the authors of those things need to fix.  In the cases where that is happening it's often because they are adding something that needs to be rendered, which means it *has* to be inside `body` in order to be part of the layout, or they are adding some JavaScript, which is commonly added to the bottom of the `body` tag so that it doesn't slow down the time to first paint.  This is often a problem even with other React components, things like Modal or Toast components need something in the body where they can attach their rendered elements, usually another `div`.

Comment: @ByteEater Hey speak for yourself, weird and hard to debug errors in production are all I need to hear to avoid that shit like the plague